# Moving data from MS Access to MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I'm trying to migrate data into SQL Server from an existing legacy set of MS Access databases. Currently everything is working except a few core tables that are wide and contain a number of `smalldatetime` columns. The problem is an error that SQL Server reports when trying to move these tables:

**Msg 8114, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
Error converting data type DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP to datetime.**

I have a stored procedure which generates dynamic sql to assist with moving each table. I converted all the `datetime` tables in SQL Server to `datetime2` columns, and I added a workaround, or so i thought, to deal with this `datetime` issue, but it doesn't seem to be working. the stored procedures are kind of bulky so the following is the relevant excerpt:

```
IF (@Conversion = 1 AND (@ColType LIKE '%date%' OR @ColType LIKE '%time%'))
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnList = @ColumnList + ', IIF(ISDATE([' + @ColName + ']) = 1, [' + @ColName + '], CONVERT(datetime2, ''12/31/1899'')) AS ['+ @ColName + ']'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnList = @ColumnList + ', [' + @ColName + ']'
    END
```

Currently, the actual data that is "bad" (can't be converted) is not really important, so I'm trying to substitute it for an obviously invalid date just to get the process to complete without errors. The MS Access frontend has no code to prevent users from entering invalid dates, so for example if someone makes a typo and creates an order with the ship date of "june 2nd, 202", instead of "2015", MS Access will happily store this and then SQL Server fails to convert that value to a `datetime`.

**EDIT:**
To clarify, this procedure is running on a schedule. I can manually repair the bad data now, but if or when more bad data is input by a user, my process will crash again.

As a test, I ran this, and got the same error:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [DRFINISH], 20) FROM [DB2_JOBS]...[Jobs]
```

However, this works:

```
SELECT TOP 100 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [DRFINISH], 20) FROM [DB2_JOBS]...[Jobs]
```

How am I going to convert the data if it causes a crash before it can even be passed into the CONVERT function??

**EDIT #2:**

These also crash:

```
SELECT [DRFINISH] FROM [DB2_JOBS]...[Jobs] WHERE ISDATE([DRFINISH]) = 1
SELECT ISDATE([DRFINISH]) FROM [DB2_JOBS]...[Jobs]
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I would appreciate it greatly.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Adba.stackexchange.com+date+conversion+from+varchar has some pretty good answers that might help.

Comment: I'm afraid I need more information to better understand your question.  Can you more thoroughly describe how you are migrating the databases?  Are you attempting to use Micrsoft's wizards to do this?  Or are you attempting to create linked tables and insert the data into them?

Comment: The MDB backends are attached as "linked servers" from inside MS SQL Server. The driver is Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0. My testing so far indicates that SQL Server is trying to translate the MS Access `smalldatetime` type into a `datetime` type before any user query code is executed. Which causes it to choke on a value that doesnt fit into SQL Server's `datetime` type, before I can cast it or check it or anything.

Comment: Even without coding, you could easily set a validation rule on the Access backend tables date fields. Something like `Between date()-365 And Date()+365` (which would limit entry to dates within +- 1 year of current date)